# Python obd doesn't connect raspberry pi to car

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, obd-ii, automotive

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 and I'm trying to hook it up to my car's OBD. I've got a Veepeak Mini Bluetooth OBD2 Scanner and I've tested it works perfectly fine with Torque on Android.

**[UPDATE AFTER UPDATING TO THE LATEST VERSION OF pythonOBD]**

It turns out there was a [commit](https://github.com/brendan-w/python-OBD/commit/d5a0fcd87b2df57cf38dd4ecd4b7b6b9cac018fd) a few days ago that introduced a delay at the `0100\r` message. This was apparently done to mitigate against a particular set of OBD scanners that didn't respond in time at that particular message. I've cloned the [repo](https://github.com/brendan-w/python-OBD) and pulled the latest from master and changed the import line to this:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(1, '/home/pi/python-OBD')
import obd
```

Now, while I was getting a separate set of logs, I was never able to get a hold of the car data. The auto protocol defaults to protocol 6 for some reason which outputs a `CAN error` after the `0100\r` message. After setting it to protocol 5, the only one that had promising results, I'm getting those logs:

```
$> python obdtest.py 
[obd.obd] ======================= python-OBD (v0.7.1) =======================
[obd.obd] Using scan_serial to select port
[obd.obd] Available ports: ['/dev/rfcomm47']
[obd.obd] Attempting to use port: /dev/rfcomm47
[obd.elm327] Initializing ELM327: PORT=/dev/rfcomm47 BAUD=38400 PROTOCOL=5
[obd.elm327] write: 'ATZ\r'
[obd.elm327] wait: 1 seconds
[obd.elm327] read: b'ATZ\r\r\rELM327 v1.5\r\r>'
[obd.elm327] write: 'ATE0\r'
[obd.elm327] read: b'ATE0\rOK\r\r>'
[obd.elm327] write: 'ATH1\r'
[obd.elm327] read: b'OK\r\r>'
[obd.elm327] write: 'ATL0\r'
[obd.elm327] read: b'OK\r\r'
[obd.elm327] write: 'AT RV\r'
[obd.elm327] read: b'13.9V\r\r>'
[obd.elm327] write: 'ATTP5\r'
[obd.elm327] read: b'OK\r'
[obd.elm327] write: '0100\r'
[obd.elm327] read: b'>'
[obd.elm327] no response; wait: 0.100000 seconds
[obd.elm327] read: b'BUS INIT: OK'
[obd.protocols.protocol] map ECU 16 --> ENGINE
[obd.elm327] Connected Successfully: PORT=/dev/rfcomm47 BAUD=38400 PROTOCOL=5
[obd.obd] querying for supported commands
[obd.obd] Sending command: 0100: Supported PIDs [01-20]
[obd.elm327] write: '0100\r'
[obd.elm327] read: b'STOPPED\r\r>'
[obd.OBDCommand] 0100: Supported PIDs [01-20] did not receive any acceptable messages
[obd.obd] No valid data for PID listing command: 0100: Supported PIDs [01-20]
[obd.obd] Sending command: 0900: Supported PIDs [01-20]
[obd.elm327] write: '0900\r'
[obd.elm327] read: b'87 F1 10 49 00 01 30 00 00 00 02 \r\r>'
[obd.obd] finished querying with 8 commands supported
[obd.obd] ===================================================================
[obd.obd] '010C: Engine RPM' is not supported
None
[obd.obd] Closing connection
[obd.elm327] closing port
[obd.elm327] write: 'ATZ\r'
```

It looks like `0100\r` is written twice and the logs return `read: b'BUS INIT: OK'` first and `read: b'STOPPED\r\r>'` second. The baudrate seems to work the same whether it's 38400 or 9600, so I don't think that's an issue either.

**[Original question]**

I've setup bluetooth on the Raspberry Pi and have paired the device, but when trying to run the following script, it works about 1 in 10 to 20 tries with the following logs:

```
import obd

obd.logger.setLevel(obd.logging.DEBUG)
connection = obd.OBD() # auto-connects to USB or RF port

cmd = obd.commands.RPM # select an OBD command (sensor)

response = connection.query(cmd) # send the command, and parse the response

print(response.value) # returns unit-bearing values thanks to Pint

connection.close()
```

When it fails (vast majority of time) it displays this:

```
$> python obdtest.py 
[obd.obd] ======================= python-OBD (v0.7.1) =======================
[obd.obd] Using scan_serial to select port
[obd.obd] Available ports: ['/dev/rfcomm47']
[obd.obd] Attempting to use port: /dev/rfcomm47
[obd.elm327] Initializing ELM327: PORT=/dev/rfcomm47 BAUD=auto PROTOCOL=auto
[obd.elm327] Response from baud 38400: '\x7f\x7f\r?\r\r>'
[obd.elm327] Choosing baud 38400
[obd.elm327] write: 'ATZ\r'
[obd.elm327] wait: 1 seconds
[obd.elm327] read: b'ATZ\r\r\rELM327 v1.5\r\r>'
[obd.elm327] write: 'ATE0\r'
[obd.elm327] read: b'ATE0\rOK\r\r>'
[obd.elm327] write: 'ATH1\r'
[obd.elm327] read: b'OK\r\r>'
[obd.elm327] write: 'ATL0\r'
[obd.elm327] read: b'OK\r\r>'
[obd.elm327] write: 'AT RV\r'
[obd.elm327] read: b'15.0V\r\r>'
[obd.elm327] write: 'ATSP0\r'
[obd.elm327] read: b'OK\r'
[obd.elm327] write: '0100\r'
[obd.elm327] read: b'>'
[obd.elm327] write: 'ATDPN\r'
[obd.elm327] read: b'SEARCHING...\r86 F1 10 41 00 BF BF F9 90 CF \r\r>'
[obd.elm327] Failed to retrieve current protocol
[obd.elm327] Adapter connected, but the ignition is off
[obd.obd] Cannot load commands: No connection to car
[obd.obd] ===================================================================
[obd.obd] '010C: Engine RPM' is not supported
None
[obd.obd] Closing connection
[obd.elm327] closing port
[obd.elm327] write: 'ATZ\r'
```

When it succeeds (1 in 10 or more tries) it displays this:

```
$> python obdtest.py 
[obd.obd] ======================= python-OBD (v0.7.1) =======================
[obd.obd] Using scan_serial to select port
[obd.obd] Available ports: ['/dev/rfcomm47']
[obd.obd] Attempting to use port: /dev/rfcomm47
[obd.elm327] Initializing ELM327: PORT=/dev/rfcomm47 BAUD=auto PROTOCOL=auto
[obd.elm327] Response from baud 38400: '\x7f\x7f\r?\r\r>'
[obd.elm327] Choosing baud 38400
[obd.elm327] write: 'ATZ\r'
[obd.elm327] wait: 1 seconds
[obd.elm327] read: b'ATZ\r\r\rELM327 v1.5\r\r>'
[obd.elm327] write: 'ATE0\r'
[obd.elm327] read: b'ATE0\rOK\r\r>'
[obd.elm327] write: 'ATH1\r'
[obd.elm327] read: b'OK\r\r>'
[obd.elm327] write: 'ATL0\r'
[obd.elm327] read: b'OK\r\r'
[obd.elm327] write: 'AT RV\r'
[obd.elm327] read: b'14.7V\r\r>'
[obd.elm327] write: 'ATSP0\r'
[obd.elm327] read: b'OK\r'
[obd.elm327] write: '0100\r'
[obd.elm327] read: b'SEARCHING...\r86 F1 10 41 00 BF BF F9 90 CF \r\r>'
[obd.elm327] write: 'ATDPN\r'
[obd.elm327] read: b'A5\r\r>'
[obd.protocols.protocol] map ECU 16 --> ENGINE
[obd.elm327] Connected Successfully: PORT=/dev/rfcomm47 BAUD=38400 PROTOCOL=5
[obd.obd] querying for supported commands
[obd.obd] Sending command: 0100: Supported PIDs [01-20]
[obd.elm327] write: '0100\r'
[obd.elm327] read: b'86 F1 10 41 00 BF BF F9 90 CF \r\r>'
[obd.obd] finished querying with 51 commands supported
[obd.obd] ===================================================================
[obd.obd] Sending command: 010C: Engine RPM
[obd.elm327] write: '010C\r'
[obd.elm327] read: b'84 F1 10 41 0C 08 3C 16 \r\r>'
527.0 revolutions_per_minute
[obd.obd] Closing connection
[obd.elm327] closing port
[obd.elm327] write: 'ATZ\r'
```

Note that `84 F1 10 41 0C 08 3C 16` is not the OBD scanner's MAC address. Also `rfcomm47` is set manually to a random value, just happened to pick 47.

What's consistent about the success logs is the number of the protocol (5). I've seen somewhere else a suggestion to just keep trying to connect, but when I'm adding something like this

```
while len(connection.supported_commands) < 100:
    connection = obd.Async("/dev/rfcomm47", protocol = "5", baudrate = "38400", fast = False, timeout = 30)
```

I'm getting those logs every time it is called from the second time on:

```
$> python sandboxobd.py 
<<startup logs>>
[obd.elm327] write: 'ATDPN\r'
[obd.elm327] read: b'SEARCHING...\r86 F1 10 41 00 BF BF F9 90 CF \r\r>'
[obd.elm327] Failed to retrieve current protocol
[obd.elm327] Adapter connected, but the ignition is off
[obd.obd] Cannot load commands: No connection to car
[obd.obd] ===================================================================
[obd.obd] ======================= python-OBD (v0.7.1) =======================
<<startup logs>>
[obd.elm327] read: b'>'
[obd.elm327] write: 'ATDPN\r'
[obd.elm327] read: b'SEARCHING...\rUNABLE TO CONNECT\r\r>'
[obd.elm327] Failed to retrieve current protocol
[obd.elm327] Adapter connected, but the ignition is off
[obd.obd] Cannot load commands: No connection to car
[obd.obd] ===================================================================
```

With the second part repeating indefinitely. Connecting directly to protocol 5 using `connection = obd.OBD(protocol="5")` gives me this:

```
[obd.elm327] Connected Successfully: PORT=/dev/rfcomm47 BAUD=38400 PROTOCOL=5
[obd.obd] querying for supported commands
[obd.obd] Sending command: 0100: Supported PIDs [01-20]
[obd.elm327] write: '0100\r'
[obd.elm327] read: b'BUS INIT: STOPPED\r\r>'
[obd.OBDCommand] 0100: Supported PIDs [01-20] did not receive any acceptable messages
[obd.obd] No valid data for PID listing command: 0100: Supported PIDs [01-20]
[obd.obd] finished querying with 7 commands supported
[obd.obd] ===================================================================
[obd.obd] '010C: Engine RPM' is not supported
None
[obd.obd] Closing connection
[obd.elm327] closing port
[obd.elm327] write: 'ATZ\r'
```

Did anybody encounter this issue before? I can't think of anything to else to try and see if it works. Any help would be greately appreciated.

Comment: What version of the library are you using? Try latest from github.

Comment: I spot two differences: 1.) in the successful log on line 19, it states `read: b'14.7V\r\r>` while on the unsuccessful it's 15.0V. 2.) on the successful logs it's first reading the searching part and then writing, whil on the unsuccessful it's the other way around. Does especially part 1.) only happen by chance? Can it be forced? I must admit I have no idea of all of this, just pointing out probably obvious stuff :)

Comment: The library has version 0.7.1 as shown in the logs. I've tried the latest master version by replacing `import obd` in the script with `with httpimport.github_repo('brendan-w', 'python-OBD', branch = 'master'): import obd` (after installing and importing httpimport via pip of course). The logs and behavior were identical as in the question.

Comment: As far as the voltage is concerned, it does vary within 1V of 15V with every run of the script, but I've had successful and unsuccessful runs with the exact same voltage. I'm not sure if I can do the handshake sequence any better, which is why I wondered if there is a way to retry part of the traffic attempts from the pi without restarting the whole connection. Or maybe the logs point to a deeper issue.

Comment: @user2565010 I still don't think you are using the latest library. Uninstall `obd` before using `httpimport`

Comment: Also, I've noticed that the failed one gets empty response to the question `0100`, and then it asks the next question (`ATDPN`) and receives "SEARCHING" as response, which is actually the response to the previous question (`0100`). Maybe adding delay after asking `0100` or retrying it a few times would help, if it's possible?

Comment: Blind guess: It feels like the library is attempting to connect to the bus to fast and the cars onboard computer doesn't have time to react and respond properly. Or there's a ground/voltage issue somewhere in the car. If not, submit a bug report on the official github repo? :)

Comment: It turns out that you were right, I wasn't using the latest version. I've cloned the latest from the repo and it turns out there was a commit a few days ago (first one in months) that addressed that particular change @hlfrmn mentioned. Now it gets past that issue, and the logs are significantly different, however it still doesn't work. I'll post an answer with a quick update, and will elaborate my problem in another question.

Comment: I don't know the respective project, but any OBD2 library that works with fixed timeouts and does not integrate a proper parser will lead to problems. If you ever see `STOPPED` in the log, it should trigger an alarm. It means, that the library sends while a command is active. A proper written ELM327 (and clones) protocol parser will never do that. Perhaps you should check an alternative library.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're specifying the protocol, in `elm327.py` you'll want to modify

`r0100 = self.__send(b"0100")` in function

`def manual_protocol(self, protocol_):` to

`r0100 = self.__send(b"0100", delay=1)`
Roughly line 224.

The commit you reference only adds the delay when `protocol` is not specified. ie: `protocol=auto`

Adding the delay helps but it's not perfect. After the connection is established I check if `obd.commands.SPEED` is supported and if not start all over.

I've also added a `delay=1` to all of the connection initialization commands (from ATZ to ATDPN) because I find without it one of them will randomly fail, the delay seems to lower the failure rate.

Lastly. `ELM327 v1.5` is a cheap clone, responses don't necessarily follow the standard.